# DIsplaying the contents on clicking the anchor tag within the same page

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have an accordion and there are some li 's inside it.On clicking the particular li anchor tag the contents of that div should be displayed by side. I have used bootstrap col-3 for the accordion and col-9 for displaying the div.All the div's are displayed and but I need to display only the clicked li's div.Can anyone help?

```js
$(function() {
  $("#profileAccordion").accordion({
    autoHeight: true
  });
  $("#profileAccordion").accordion({
    collapsible: true
  });
});
```

```css
#personalInformation,
#changePassword,
#loginHistory,
#addUser {
  //display: none;
}

#personalInformation:focus {
  display: block;
  color: Red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.100.1/css/materialize.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-3">
    <div id="profileAccordion">
      <h3>My Profile <i class="fa fa-angle-down pull-right " aria-hidden="true "></i></h3>

      <ol>
        <li><a href="#personalInformation">Personal Information</a></li>
        <li><a href="#changePassword">Change My Password</a></li>
        <li><a href="#loginHistory">Login History</a></li>
        <li><a href="#addUser">Add User</a></li>
      </ol>

      <h3>Everest Settings <i class="fa fa-angle-down pull-right " aria-hidden="true "></i></h3>

      <div>
        <ol>
          <li>My Dashboard</li>
          <li>Language & Time Zone</li>
        </ol>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-9" style="border-left: 1px solid #ccc;">
    <div id="personalInformation">
      <div class="row form-group">
        <div class="col-sm-10">
          <h4>Personal Information</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-2 marbot5 pull-right">
          <a class="text-link " ui-sref=" " href="# ">Edit</a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <hr>
      <div class="row ">
        <div class="col-sm-12">

          hello USer

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="personalInformation">
      <div class="row form-group" id="personalInformation">
        <div class="col-sm-10">
          <h4>Add User</h4>
        </div>
      </div>
      <hr>
      <div class="row ">
        <div class="col-sm-12">

          <div class="row form-group">
            <label class="col-sm-3 control-label" for="firstname">Name<span class="mandatory">*</span></label>
            <div class="col-sm-5"> <input class="form-control" placeholder="" /></div>
          </div>
          <div class="row form-group">
            <label class="col-sm-3 control-label" for="firstname">Company</label>
            <div class="col-sm-5"> <input class="form-control" placeholder="" /></div>
          </div>
          <div class="row form-group">
            <label class="col-sm-3 control-label" for="firstname">Title</label>
            <div class="col-sm-5"> <input class="form-control" placeholder="" /></div>
          </div>
          <div class="row form-group">
            <label class="col-sm-3 control-label" for="firstname">E-mail<span class="mandatory">*</span></label>
            <div class="col-sm-5"> <input class="form-control" placeholder="" /></div>
          </div>
          <div class="row form-group">
            <label class="col-sm-3 control-label" for="firstname">Work</label>
            <div class="col-sm-5"> <input class="form-control" value="+1" type="tel" international-phone-number auto-hide-dial-code="false" class="phone" name="phoneCountryCode" ng-model="phone" placeholder="" required></div>
          </div>

          <div class="row form-group">
            <label class="col-sm-3 control-label" for="firstname">Mobile</label>
            <div class="col-sm-5"> <input class="form-control" value="+1" type="tel" international-phone-number auto-hide-dial-code="false" class="phone" name="phoneCountryCode" ng-model="phone" required></div>
          </div>

          <div class="row form-group">
            <label class="col-sm-3 control-label" for="firstname">User Level<span class="mandatory">*</span></label>
            <div class="col-sm-5">
              <select class="form-control placeholder-color ">
                            <option value=" " disabled selected>--Select User Level--</option>     
                            <option value=" ">Super Admin</option>
                            <option value=" ">Executive</option>
                            <option value=" ">Manager</option>
                            <option value=" ">Team Member</option>
                        </select>
              <i class="fa fa-angle-down pull-right " aria-hidden="true "></i></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="changePassword">
      <div class="row form-group">
        <div class="col-sm-10">
          <h4>Change Password</h4>
        </div>
      </div>


      <div class="row">

        <div class="col-sm-10">

          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-offset-3">
              <form class="form-horizontal">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="" class="col-sm-4 control-label">Current Password</label>
                  <div class="col-sm-8"><input type="text" class="form-control" id="lastname" placeholder=""></div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="" class="col-sm-4 control-label">New Password</label>
                  <div class="col-sm-8"><input type="text" class="form-control" id="lastname" placeholder=""></div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="" class="col-sm-4 control-label">Confirm Password</label>
                  <div class="col-sm-8"><input type="text" class="form-control" id="lastname" placeholder=""></div>
                </div>


              </form>
            </div>
          </div>

        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row form-footer">
        <div class="col-md-5 col-md-offset-1"><a href="#" class="btn text-link pull-left">Cancel</a></div>
        <div class="col-md-5"><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary pull-right" ng-click="newpasswordsubmitted()">Save &amp; Update</button></div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-12 text-right">
        <a class="btn btn-default" href="# ">Cancel</a> <a class="btn btn-primary" href="# ">Save</a>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why do you include two versions of the jQuery library?

Comment: Okay,by mistake I added the snippet's jquery option too.

Comment: *«I'm unable to display the content on clicking»* is unclear. Be more specific about what to display on click of which element. Your snippet seems to be running correctly.

Comment: On clicking the li element,I need to show the corresponding div id ,for example,If i click on personal information in the accordion ,I need to the display the personal information div.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I added an id named 'mylist' to your ol and did this;

```
  $("#mylist > li > a").click(function () {
     var href = $(this).attr('href');
     $(href).fadeToggle();
  });
```

See it in action here;

https://jsfiddle.net/hbox25h8/1/

You might need a little refinement to account for user behavior.

Comment: Can't we use only css to achieve this? with jquery I already did it,But using css can't we achieve?

Comment: You really should have said this in your question.

No you can't use just CSS, but you could use plain Javascript. Personally, I'd stick with jQuery.

Comment: I do not need toggle,I need to show that corresponding div only.

Comment: Just change it to .show() or .fadeIn() instead then https://jsfiddle.net/hbox25h8/2/

Comment: I already gave .show.I 'm able to see the other div's too.Sorry,Let me be more clear,If I click  on personal details I need to show only that div, the other div's should not be shown.

Comment: On my demo if you click on persnal details it shows just the personal details div?

Comment: It shows but on clicking the change password , I'm able to see the other div's too.

Comment: Take a look at your HTML and where you're using your ID's! You have ID's on the incorrect divs. You're also using the same ID more than once, which you should never do.

Comment: That's quite cool, but you would need to add every id in to your CSS to maintain the menu. I think this is maybe what you're after if you want to use jQuery https://jsfiddle.net/hbox25h8/4/

Comment: That's great.Thank you. :)

Comment: Welcome. You should probably mark this as the correct answer to your question. In the future I would advise more clarify in your original question and ensuring your HTML is in good order.

Comment: Sure.I have accepted.Could you please update the answer to that js fiddle link.Because I think that's the correct answer.